# How can I make the operations on PL/PGSQL work in a parallel thread?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

For example:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE _id int;
BEGIN
    UPDATE table SET data = data + 1 WHERE id = _id;

    PARALLEL TASK START
         -- very long operation recalc
         PERFORM proc_exec_some_big_operation_recalc(_id);
         -- redist inform, that data updated
         PERFORM proc_inform_data_updated_apps(_id);
    PARALLEL TASK END;

    -- return immediate response as a result of the function
    RETURN 'success';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I need this function for two reasons:
- when it is required to carry out lengthy data conversion operations, but the result of the function must be returned (for example, about changing data) immediately
- when you want to notify many applications to tell that the data has changed. But at the same time you need to be sure that the data is really recorded

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because PL/pgSQL, and indeed the PostgreSQL backend, are single-threaded.

You should use [PL/Proxy](https://plproxy.github.io/), which is written exactly for problems like yours.